# Toggle Mapbox GL JS map interactiveness after map load

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

It is possible to change if a map is interactive or not after creating a map?

In the mapbox-gl-js documentation it is only possible to flag the map as interactive or non interactive when creating the map (option.interactive). But for some reasons I need to change it on the fly and toggle map interactiveness. Something like:

```
map.setInteractive(true);
```

or:

```
map.setInteractive(false);
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: There's an example demonstrating how to enable or disable map interactions here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-interaction-handlers/

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it, by disabling each of the map handlers:

(currently working on `mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0`)

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});

// disable map interaction so users can't pan, zoom, etc
map.boxZoom.disable();
map.scrollZoom.disable();
map.dragPan.disable();
map.dragRotate.disable();
map.keyboard.disable();
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.touchZoomRotate.disable();
```

Handlers are documented here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Handlers

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox GL JS does not currently have a dynamic setter for changing the interactivity of the map. This would be relatively simple to implement, so if you'd like to cut a ticket, or preferably submit a PR, on the [github repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/) we would definitely consider adding this feature.

In the meantime, you can enable / disable all the interaction [handlers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Handlers) individually to achieve the same effect dynamically after the map has been created.